# labels in bar chart touches the top horizontal line

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am trying to create a bar chart within a shiny context. Everything looks good but the labels. As you can see in the below image, some of the labels are hidden behind the top horizontal line.

[image]

```
    Diff_plot <- reactive({
    ggplot(Diff_data(), aes(x =Difficulty_Type, y = Percentage, fill=County.y)) + geom_bar(stat =
                                                                       "identity",
                                                                       position = position_dodge()
             ) +

      scale_fill_manual(values=cbbPalette)+

      geom_text(
        aes(label = Percentage2),
        vjust = 0,
        colour = "black", 
        position = position_dodge(width=0.9),
        fontface = "bold",
        size=4,
        angle = 90,
        hjust = 0
      ) + 
      labs(
        x = "",
        y = "Frequecny",

        face = "bold"
      ) +
      theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(
        hjust = 0.5,
        size = 15,
        colour = "Black",
        face = "bold"
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of `hjust` and `vjust` to set the text on top of your bargraph.

Using `hjust = -1`, you will get more space between the top of your bargraph and the text. If your text is hidden by the top horizontal line, you can increase limits of y axis by using `ylim`

```r
df <- data.frame(X = LETTERS[1:3],
                 Y = sample(1:10,3),
                 labels = letters[4:6])

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x = X, y = Y, label = labels))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(angle = 90, hjust = -1, vjust = 0.5)+
  ylim(0,6.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to define the ylim as a function of the maximum of y values plus some constant value. Something like this: ylim (0, Max Y+5). Also, I was wondering if I can combine this statement with your proposed one: scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)

Comment: Sure, in `scale_y_continuous`, you can add the argument `limits` which is the same thing than `ylim`. You could define y limits by for example: `limits = c(0, max(df$y)*0.5)`. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: In `scale_y_continuous` you can also use `expand` option. That would add some padding around the data.

Comment: Thank you both. I added limits = c(0, max(df$y)*0.5) to my syntax and got an error. Also, tried limits = c(0, 1) but got the error: nonnumeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a reproducible example of your dataset in order we can test it ? Such as `dput(NameofYourDataframe)` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)